# Make a div 100% + 50px wide, or crop an image but make the remainder full width

Tags: css

I have the following image:

[image]

On mobile, I'd like the right edge of this image to exceed the right edge of the screen, so the curved portion @ right of the image is cropped, but the remaining image is 100% wide.

[image]

Is it possible to make its containing div be 100% + 50px wide? I've tried

```
width: calc(100% + 50px)
```

but this wasn't applied.

Or is there a way to crop the image, but make the remainder full width?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also use `clip-path` function to crop the image and it will also retain the width of the container.

Here is the snippet for image cropping, you can wrap it in container as per your needs.

```css
:root {
    --cropSize: 50px;
}

.container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    max-width: 500px;
}

.inner-container {
    width: calc(100% + var(--cropSize));
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    clip-path: polygon(
        0 0,
        calc(100% - var(--cropSize)) 0,
        calc(100% - var(--cropSize)) 100%,
        0% 100%
    );
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner-container">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/61aIt.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Nik. When I try the code, it leaves a gap where the crop is. The image doesn't expand to occupy the cropped out space.

Comment: I've updated the code. It will now fill the gap. @Steve

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution, the HTML should be something like this.

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="image" style="background-image:URL()"><img src=""></div>
</div>
```

The container is used to set `overflow:hidden`. The `background-image` is used to make sure the image won't be stretched when we change its size by adding `background-size:cover|contain`.

To make the image exceed 50px to the right, you can use a minus margin, notice that you have to set `width:auto` to let the `margin` changes the `width`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use `overflow: hidden;` on image's parent container, so the code is like this

```
<div style="width: calc(100% - 150px); overflow: hidden;">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/61aIt.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  img {
  max-width: 100%;
  --cropSize:50px;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - var(--cropSize)) 0, calc(100% - var(--cropSize)) 100%, 0% 100%);
}
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/61aIt.jpg" />
```

- Change crop size variable if required,
- Here we use `clip-path` to crop size
- And we use media screen to check weather device is mobile/desktop, *open in full page and* **try resizing the page width**

Comment: The image doesn't expand to occupy the cropped space. I would like the cropped space to not appear as empty white space.

Comment: do you want to stretch image or crop image to fill space

Comment: Whatever works, but the right border of the visible image needs to be, say, 50px to the left of where it is now, but hard up against the right side of the screen, with no gap where the cropped out portion of the image was.